# Use of Ifelse and Or in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset named SPT which has one column which consist 4 unique values-A,B,C,D, Now I have to create one more column which consist of 1 if first column had A, B otherwise 0.How to do it using ifelse command

Comment: Try `df1$newcol <- as.integer(all(c("A", "B") %in% df1$col))`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ifelse:

```
SPT$new <- ifelse(SPT$col %in% c('A','B'),1,0)
```

Where new must be changed by the name of your new variable, and col by the name of the column that is storing the 4 letters

Comment: Thanks. I used the syntax and its working perfectly well